# C Search for a string match in a Sorted Binary Tree

Tags: c, string, binary-search-tree

I have 2 files: dictionary and sample.

```
void print_table (Table);
void print_stats (Table);
```

Comment: Dose `Key_Type` can check in `<` and  `==` (number type)?

Comment: No idea what you said.

Comment: drop return value of `search(key, tab->head);`

Comment: so delete the "return FALSE"?

Comment: no, maybe `if(search(key, tab->head)) return TRUE; else return FALSE;`

Comment: Thx, but no change. The output is still the same. Do you want me to add the entire code? Although the problem should be in this one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48309/discussion-between-sarah-and-bluepixy)

Comment: Please post the declaration of your node class.  Also the problem you state in text above doesn't match your own output.

Comment: I think comparing equivalence test is not working probably.

Comment: Ok, I'll post the entire code.

Comment: What's `Key_Type`'s definition?

Comment: I've added that to my code

Comment: thanks that was what I suspected it was

Comment: Please strongly consider removing the tag for binary, it has nothing do with this question.  binary-search perhaps, but not binary.

Comment: Use `strcmp` to compare cstrings.

Comment: BLUEPIXY could you please be more specific about the strcmp? I am already using that in my insert method.

Comment: you will also need to use in the search method.

Comment: Tried that, got a trillion errors, I will update the code so you can see

Comment: refer to the UpAndAdam's answer. E.g `strcmp(key,head->element) == 0` : Equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems:
- <s>You are always returning false from `find`</s>  Fixed by user
- You are always adding a print out of 'not found' whenever the root of the search isn't a match.

> ```
>   else if(key<head->element)
>   {   printf("not found");
>       return search(key, head->left);
> ```

And the bigger two problems

- You are in `C` language and `key` and `head->element` are both const char* or char*; you can't use the `==` operator on them.  That will only work if the pointers point to the same address. You want to use `strcmp` instead.
- You don't want to compare `key` to `head->left`; you probably mean to compare to `head->left->element`.  Otherwise you are comparing a char* to a node*. But again `strcmp` simplifies all of this, as you actually don't need to and shouldn't do this check here; particularly as head->left might itself be `NULL`.

As in below:

```
struct node *search( Key_Type key, struct node *head )
{
    if ( head != NULL)
    {
        //note change to strcmp
        int res = strcmp( key, head->element );
        if ( !res )
        {
            printf("found");
            return head;
        }
        else if( res < 0 ) //note change to strcmp.
        {
            printf( "not found" );
            return search( key, head->left );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "found3" );
            return search( key, head->right );
        }
    }
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, but I do have to return a boolean value from find, since it is a boolean method.

Comment: Edited to remove that out.

Comment: head->left->element gives me the error:  warning: passing argument 2 of ‘search’ from incompatible pointer type

Comment: @Sarah See the updated post which should make my point clearer.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I've updated the code to your suggestions but now the output is: Dictionary read  
word:a  
word:b  
word:c  
word:d  
word:e  
Spellchecking:  
found3foundfoundfoundUsage

Comment: For some reason, a b z are not getting outputted anymore

Comment: I would suggest using a debugger and stepping through at this point, and also instead of printing 'found' and 'found3' perhaps use your print_node function.   I just fixed your search function; that's what the post asked :-)

Comment: Can you suggest any good debuggers? Also, perhaps I did not make myself clear but "What I want is to output a - found b - found -z not found". So it's not been fixed yet

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48312/discussion-between-upandadam-and-sarah)